# Using bash for loop to run Python doctest from a separate file located in subdirectories

Tags: python, bash, shell, for-loop, doctest

I am testing a large amount of student's python projects. I created a doctest in a separate file I have called, say, `mydoctest.rst`.

The first line of the doctest imports student's project's module:

> from project3 import functionname

The doctest works fine when I call it from the same directory as student's project:

```
studentA$ python3 -m doctest mydoctest.rst
```

What I would like do is use a bash for loop command to do the above for each subdirectory, so I tried doing the following.

```
parentdirectory$ for d in *; do python3 -m doctest "$d/"mydoctest.rst; done
```

But then it tries to look for the module in the current directory instead of in each subdirectory.

Is there a way to first cd into each subdirectory before doing `do python3 -m doctest`?

My current workaround (which I am not happy with) is:
    for d in *; do cd "$d";  python3 -m doctest mydoctest.rst;  cd ..; done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
for d in *; do (cd "$d" ; python3 -m doctest mydoctest.rst); done
```

Comment: What is the difference between using `;` and `&&` ? They seem to do the same thing.

Comment: && will launch the command after it in a new thread (but the same environment) and there is no guarantee that the command before it will have completed before it launches. Though for something small like "cd", this will likely have completed in time.

Comment: I think you are talking about '&'. ; is a serialization operator, it will do first the command before ; then the command after. & will do them both immediately, without waiting for each other. && is a boolean operator, it will first evaluate the first command, and if it is false it will know the whole expression is false, so it won't evaluate the second command. If the first command is true, it will evaluate the second command to see if that is true as well.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use a subshell `(...)` and `cd`:

```
for d in *; do (cd "$d" && python3 -m doctest mydoctest.rst); done
```

Comment: I took your answer and make it work for my grading process: `for d in *; do (cd "$d" ; python3 -m doctest doctest3.rst ; echo $PWD); done`

Comment: @egunawan Just click on the "tick" mark below the "up/down vote" button.